# run time error (ArrayOutOfBoundException)

Tags: java

Getting a run time error `ArrayOutOfBoundException`

```
class Command
{   
    public static void main(String[] args)  
    {       
       int a,b,c,sum;                       
       a = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);       
       b = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);       
       c = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);       
       sum = a+b+c;         
       System.out.println("Command Line Sum is "+sum);          
     }     
 }
```

// what is error in this code ?

Comment: what instruction did you enter to run the code?

Comment: Have you read about this exception before posting it here?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html

Comment: Do you have a value coming in for `String[] args`? If not, then you are trying to parse non-existent information.

Answer (score 2):

An `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` occurs when you try to reference an index that does not exist in an array. Here, you're implicitly assuming that you give the program three arguments (or more). If it's run with no arguments, `args[0]` will generate this exception. If it's run with one argument, you'll get the exception on `args[1]` and if it's run with two arguments, `args[2]` will cause said exception.

Answer (score 1):

As the responses above have stated, the exception you are experiencing is because you are trying to access an element of the array that is past the maximum length of the array.

There are a couple ways that you can go about handling this. First, if you want to make sure that there must ALWAYS be 3 arguments send to your program, you could throw an exception like so:

```
    if (args.length < 3) {
        throw new Exception("This program requires 3 arguments");
    }
```

On the other hand, if you just wanted to sum up all of the arguments that were sent to your program, with no concern on how many arguments were sent to it, you can use a foreach loop (see documentation and more examples [HERE](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/flow/loops/foreach.html)). This can be achieved like so:

```
    int sum = 0;
    for(String intString : args){
        sum += Integer.parseInt(intString);
    }
```

If you are looking for more of an explanation on why this is happening, it has to do with how arrays are handled in memory. When an array is initialized in memory, it is given a specific number of bytes in which are allocated as memory for the array. Outside of those bytes, are memory values and locations that can correspond to anything else happening at that time, that have nothing to do with your array. Think of it like a fenced off yard, when you are trying to access something inside of the array, you are inside of the fence and everything goes well. But, when you try to access something outside of the array, you are trying to get over the fence into a place where you do not belong.

This is happening most likely because 3 values were not passed into your program as arguments. So your fence may have only contained 1 square foot, and you were trying to get over the fence to the 3rd square foot, an area which was not  yours.

Answer (score 0):

you need to invoke with all 3 arguments, or you will get arrayindexoutofboundsexception

```
class Command {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


    if(args.length != 3){
        throw new Exception("You must set all three arguments, a,b,c");
    }

    if(null == args[0]){
        throw new Exception("a not supplied");
    }

    if(null == args[1]){
        throw new Exception("b not supplied");
    }

    if(null == args[2]){
        throw new Exception("c not supplied");
    }

    int a, b, c, sum;
    a = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    b = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    c = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
    sum = a + b + c;
    System.out.println("Command Line Sum is " + sum);
}
```

}